# Как сохранить сессию браузера при работе с библиотекой selenium?

Tags: html, python, парсер, selenium

Нужно залогиниться на сайте и потом перейти на главную страницу нажав кнопку "На главную", для дальнейшего парсинга. Логирование получается реализовать:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
type(browser)
browser.get('https://www.qrz.ru/passport/login')
emailElem = browser.find_element_by_id('email-login')
emailElem.send_keys('емейл.ru')
passElem = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
passElem.send_keys('123456')
passElem.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
```

Оказываюсь на своей страничке в личном кабинете.
А вот дальше как быть? Как перейти на главную страницу?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете сохранить текущие куки как объект python, используя pickle. Например:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

а потом добавить их обратно:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

[отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver)